# Catboost runs correctly on onnx but does not work on OpenVINO

Tags: intel, onnx, openvino, catboost, catboostregressor

I tried to convert to OpenVINO a Catboost model implemented by me, before I had to transform the Catboost to ONNX, I used the code found at the following link: https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/apply-onnx-ml
Then from ONNX to OpenVINO. When I run this code the following warning appeared:
"OpenVINO does not support the following ONNX operations:
ai.onnx.ml. TreeEnsembleRegressor".
How can I solve this problem?
Is there a way to extend OpenVINO to include the above ONNX operations?

I hope to find solutions to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following operation "ai.onnx.ml. TreeEnsembleRegressor" is currently not supported in OpenVINO Toolkit.

Refer the [Supported Operations - by Framework Frontend](https://docs.openvino.ai/2023.1/openvino_resources_supported_operations_frontend.html) documentation for lists of supported ONNX operations.